# How to retrieve the client (browser) timezone in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: timezone, vaadin

I need to determine the browser timezone. I tried to follow [this post](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18253436/how-do-you-get-the-client-timezone-in-version-14) but does not work (Vaadin 20). Here is my code:

```
    ZoneId myZoneId;
    ...

    UI.getCurrent().getPage().retrieveExtendedClientDetails(extendedClientDetails -> {
      myZoneId = ZoneId.of(extendedClientDetails.getTimeZoneId());
    });

    // here myZoneId has value null.
```

So I tried to do it myself, initially simply displaying it.

```
    UI.getCurrent().getPage()
            .executeJs("return Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;")
            .then(value -> Notification.show(value.asString()));
```

It works and I read "Europe/Rome", but its value does not seem something that I can map to a ZoneId in Java.

I could explore a little more the Javascript zone object but I also was unable to find where my code actually went to debug it with chrome debugger (there is no mention in Vaadin doc where the code goes).

I could work on the returned value and try to interpret it but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Do anybody has any code that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody!

Finally the main problem was not retrieving the time zone from the client but matching it against the list of available time zones returned by `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. The fact is that there were multiple timezone for CEST (Central Europe) as well as any other country. I counted 7 for Brazil that only has 5 time zones!

Honestly I am little ignorant about time zones (world would be quite simpler if we could use only GMT and adjust our schedules accordingly). The solution was to digest the timezone list using the name. I do not know if this is right or wrong, but it is simple and works, despite the fact that if I choose CEST I do not know if it will be Rome, Berlin or whatever else. Does it matter?

[image]

Here is the complete code if somebody should one day need a

```
package net.cbsolution.scc.vaadin.comps;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ItemLabelGenerator;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.ListDataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.TemplateRenderer;

import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TimeZoneSelector extends ComboBox<ZoneId> {
  private Locale locale = UI.getCurrent().getLocale();

  public TimeZoneSelector() {

    // Digest the timezone list
    final Map<String, ZoneId> cleanMap = new HashMap<>();
    ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().map(z -> ZoneId.of(z)).forEach(z -> cleanMap.put(print(z), z));

    cleanMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    setWidth("20em");
    setDataProvider(new ListDataProvider<>(cleanMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())));
    setRenderer(TemplateRenderer.<ZoneId>of("<span>[[item.print]]</span>")
        .withProperty("print", tz -> print(tz))
    );
    setItemLabelGenerator((ItemLabelGenerator<ZoneId>) item -> print(item));
  }

  protected String print(ZoneId zoneId) {
    return zoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().retrieveExtendedClientDetails(details -> {
      TimeZone uiTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(details.getTimeZoneId());
      setValue(ZoneId.of(uiTimeZone.getID()));
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, could you also mark the answer accepted?

Comment: This contains some deprecated calls as of Vaadin 22.
LitRenderer is now preferred over TemplateRenderer, 
and setItems is now preferred over setDataProvider. Other than changing those, I also needed to change 
"[[item.print]]" to "${item.print}". It then seemed to work in Vaadin 23.1.2, the current version at this moment. Thanks for posting your code :-)

Answer (score 2):

`retrieveExtendedClientDetails` is an asynchronous call, thus the result is available **inside** the callback and not right *after* firing the callback (on the place you commented).

Also, `UI.getCurrent()` could return `null` if called too soon, f.e. in a constructor.

`retrieveExtendedClientDetails` makes a client roundtrip the **first time** it is run [(docs)](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.7.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/page/Page.html#retrieveExtendedClientDetails-com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Page.ExtendedClientDetailsReceiver-).

> If already obtained, the callback is called directly. Otherwise, a client-side roundtrip will be carried out.

That means you could try to run it when initialising the UI and later you should have it ready right away after firing.

```java
@SpringComponent
public class MyVaadinServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {
    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addUIInitListener(uiEvent -> {   
            var ui = event.getUI();
            ui.getPage().retrieveExtendedClientDetails(detail -> {});
        });
    }    
}
```

---

Another solution is to read the zone inside the callback.

Comment: No, if you look at my code I save the variable and use it later. What you see used is the variable set after the promise is done, the same I do in my js code. What happens (if I debug the code) is that something goes wrong inside the call. That's why I decided to call js instead of debugging somebody else code.

Answer (score 1):

Europe/Rome is fine for Java.

You can simply call:

```
ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I think my question was in part incomplete. Let me explain the need: I show a combo box to the user where she will select a time zone (and this works). I get possible timezones calling ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds(). Then I would set the initial value to client default. It happens (localization apart) that Rome is not there (neither in English nor in any other language). It is probably Berlin or whatever else. But your suggestion gave me an idea: I will loop through te set and see if equals match any other.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//Read the timezone and store in into the session class
if(UI.getCurrent() != null) {      
       UI.getCurrent().getPage().retrieveExtendedClientDetails(details -> {
                           
        // Set the time zone
        TimeZone uiTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(details.getTimeZoneId());
                            
      });
 };
```

Comment: Yes, it worked (return Europe/Rome like my JS) but then could not find a match in the list, this was the actual problem.